# Substitution method for definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, substitution

If I am trying to solve a definite integral by means of a substitution, my teacher told me that the substitution function cannot have any extrema in the interval of integration.

Is there any way to get around this problem? Perhaps by splitting about the point of extremum.

Comment: It would help if you provide the example you are talking about...

Comment: extrema or discontinuity?

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, you'll find several related questions (and answers!) here: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+integral+substitution+injective